# which is vs being

Tags: word-choice

When I was searching for information about ''which is vs being'', 
I found information about this topic.
It said that using **''which is''** '' is not idiomatic to use in the following sentence;

***sentence a)***"Various assumptions must be made during the course of a force analysis reflecting the specific characteristics of the particular system **being** investigated"  _____correct one.

***sentence b)*** "Various assumptions must be made during the course of a force analysis reflecting the specific characteristics of the particular system ***which is*** investigated"  _______incorrect one

If someone can explain that situation (why ***''being''***  correct ,***''which is''*** incorrect? )

I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to understand the "deep" structure of the sentences:

> "...the specific characteristics of the particular system [**which is being** investigated]."

The part in brackets [ ]  is a *relative clause* which modifies "system". The rules of *reduced relative clauses* allow us to omit "which is", so sentence a) is correct.

The deep structure of the sentence is in **present continuous passive**, while sentence b) is in **simple present passive**. In this context, simple present is incorrect, so sentence b) is incorrect.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved if it explained *why* the simple present is not idiomatic here, since that seems to be the crux of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should offset the clause by a comma when using "which", as in:

> Various assumptions must be made during the course of a force analysis reflecting the specific characteristics of the particular system, which is investigated.

This changes the meaning and is probably not what you intend. You could use "that" without a comma, as in :

> Various assumptions must be made during the course of a force analysis reflecting the specific characteristics of the particular system that is investigated.

However, **"being investigated" is the best choice**, because it gives an impression that the investigation is ongoing during the force analysis.

Comment: Why should there be a comma or a change of the relative pronoun? While only "which" can introduce a non-restrictive relative clause, **either** "which" or "that" can introduce a restrictive relative clause. The version without the comma is restrictive, which is the intent of the original sentence. So, it would be correct as-is *if* the relative clause were OK at all, but it seems not to be. I agree with your last sentence - the *reason* the relative clause is wrong is that it changes the aspect from continuous to simple (as @gotube also mentions).

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Yes, I suppose that avoiding 'which' with a restrictive relative clause is really a style choice. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: While I wouldn't choose either option with the relative clause, I do agree with you that "that" sounds better than "which." I was just saying that I don't see any reason *why* that should be so -- if there *is* an explanation, it's not one I could provide.